# How to convert array with elements utf8 strings to NSArray with elements utf8 strings in objective c

Tags: objective-c

The variable `utfStringArray` is type `unsigned char **` and points some UTF-8 strings. How to convert this array to a type of `NSArray *` with same strings without using `NSString *`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `utfStringArray` is terminated with a `NULL`, else you'll need to provide the element count separately.  I am also assuming ARC.  Note I am using `NSData` as you have stipulated that `NSString`'s cannot be used (for some reason):

```
unsigned char **utfStringArray = ...;
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (unsigned i = 0; utfStringArray[i] != NULL; i++)
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:utfStringArray[i] 
                                  length:strlen(utfStringArray[i])];
    [array addObject:data];
}
```